# Oracle data adapter concat in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
OracleDataAdapter da1 = new OracleDataAdapter("select CONCAT(aut_vardas,' ', aut_pavarde) AS autorius from autoriai", conn);
```

Oracle data adapter not executing this query, what is wrong in concat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the problem is that your version of Oracle supports `concat()` but it only takes two arguments, or you are using a really, really old version of Oracle that doesn't have `concat()`.  In any case, the following should work:

```
select (aut_vardas || ' ' || aut_pavarde) AS autorius
from autoriai;
```